# Gorm returns Scanner error on custom string type

Tags: go, go-gorm

I wrote the below entity:

```golang
type DataCategory string

const (
    DataCategory1 DataCategory = "Category1"
    DataCategory2 DataCategory = "Category2"
)

type Data struct {
    Name            string         `json:"name"`
    Categories      []DataCategory `json:"category" gorm:"type:text[]"`
}
```

I manually created a row in the database and filled the categories array type with Category1 and Category2.

But this gives the below error when reading the data:

```
sql: Scan error on column index 19, name "category": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type string into type *[]DataCategory
```

---

Example Value method:

```golang
func (s DataCategorySlice) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    if s == nil {
        return nil, nil
    }
    if len(s) == 0 {
        return "{}", nil
    }

    v := []string{}
    for _, dc := range s {
        v = append(v, string(dc))
    }
    result := fmt.Sprintf("{%s}", strings.Join(v, ","))
    return result, nil
}
```

Comment: If you want other than the most basic types to work with Gorm you'll need to _declare_ the types first and then you'll need to implement the `sql.Scanner` and `driver.Valuer` interfaces with those types.

Comment: @mkopriva, can you give an example? Because the only way I was able to find is to create new enum type in the database and use a Scanner/Valuer.

Comment: I've added an example implementation as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example assumes that you're using PostgreSQL as the RDBMS and that the `DataCategory` values do not contain commas nor unescaped single quotes.

```golang
// declare the custom type
type DataCategorySlice []DataCategory
```

```golang
// implement driver.Valuer to encode the value into the
// correct format that is accepted by the target RDBMS
func (s DataCategorySlice) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    if s == nil {
        return nil, nil
    }
    if len(s) == 0 {
        return []byte(`{}`), nil
    }

    v := []byte(`{`)
    for i := range s {
        v = append(v, s[i]...)
        v = append(v, ',')
    }
    v[len(v)-1] = '}' // replace last comma with closing brace
    return v, nil
}
```

```golang
// implement scanner to decode the raw source
// value as retrieved from the database
func (s *DataCategorySlice) Scan(src any) error {
    var data []byte
    switch v := src.(type) {
    case []byte:
        data = v
    case string:
        data = []byte(v)
    case nil:
        return nil
    default:
        return fmt.Errorf("unsupported type: %T", src)
    }
    if len(data) == 0 {
        return nil
    }
    data = data[1:len(data)-1] // remove surrounding braces
    for _, v := range bytes.Split(data, []byte{','}) {
        *s = append(*s, DataCategory(v))
    }
    return nil
}
```

---

Alternatively, if returning `[]byte` from `Value() (driver.Value, error)` doesn't work, e.g. it results in `"ERROR: malformed array literal: <hex representation of the field's value> (SQLSTATE 22P02)"`, then you can try using `string` as the return type instead.

*<sub>example from [@kozhioyrin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14374932/kozhioyrin)</sub>*

```golang
// implement driver.Valuer to encode the value into the
// correct format that is accepted by the target RDBMS
func (s DataCategorySlice) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    if s == nil {
        return nil, nil
    }
    if len(s) == 0 {
        return "{}", nil
    }

    v := []string{}
    for _, dc := range s {
        v = append(v, string(dc))
    }
    result := fmt.Sprintf("{%s}", strings.Join(v, ","))
    return result, nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. I like the idea and this example is almost working, except the Value method. It should return a string value I guess. I'll try to edit my posting so you can check it.

Comment: Are you sure, or are you just guessing? Returning `[]byte` as `driver.Value` from `Value()` generally works, i've been using that for ages with stdlib's `database/sql` and `lib/pq`, though I don't use gorm so maybe it has some quirky behaviour?

Comment: I had to change it because it was returning error such as "ERROR: malformed array literal: <hex representation of the field's value> (SQLSTATE 22P02)"

Comment: I see, perhaps that's gorm's doing or the driver's that gorm utilizes. I'll update the answer.